# How to execute applications with super-user privileges in Gnome-Do

Tags: gnome-do, gksu, xampp

I want to execute XAMPP CONTROL PANEL via Gnome-Do. But after I typed the `sudo`password for authentication nothing happened. The Laucher is located in `/opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel` and executes `gksudo python /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py` properly. How can I do that with Gnome-Do?

Answer (score 2):

You should never use sudo to launch graphical applications. Use gksudo instead. If you want to shorten the command, then you can make a file such as this:

```
#!/bin/bash
gksudo some command
```

Place it somewhere you like, in /usr/bin, for instance and make it executable. Then you can just run filname (the name you gave the file) to run it. It will ask for your password and run the command as root.

Comment: Where does Gnome-do find the executable files?

Comment: Better to put in `~/bin` for a single user, or in `/usr/local/bin` if to be run from other users too.